# Touch scroll in a PySide QScrollArea

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyside, qscrollarea

Implementing kinetic scrolling under Qt5 is quite simple with the QScroller class, but this unfortunately isn't an option currently with PySide, as PySide is Qt4-based, and PySide 2 (Qt5-based) doesn't yet have QScroller support.

I have a QScrollArea with a grid of QButtons inside. How would I go about implementing touch scrolling on the QScrollArea? Do I have to install a myriad of eventFilters, for both the QScrollArea and each QButton, to ensure a click and drag of the screen isn't interpreted as a clicked() event on one of the buttons?